# XAMPP issues, MySQL won't start

Tags: mysql, xampp

New here, so please go easy on me.

I have XAMPP installed on a Windows 11 machine, been working fine until today, then MySQL starts throwing error messages and wont start.
The copy and paste from the error log is.

```
2022-09-28 21:05:41 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-09-28 21:06:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-09-28 21:06:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-09-28 21:06:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-09-28 21:06:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-09-28 21:06:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-09-28 21:06:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-09-28 21:06:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-09-28 21:06:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-09-28 21:06:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-09-28 21:06:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-09-28 21:06:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-09-28 21:06:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-09-28 21:06:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 41489485; transaction id 88873
2022-09-28 21:06:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-09-28 21:06:05 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

2022-09-28 21:06:05 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Any ideas please

Many thanks

Here is the content of the error log

```
2022-09-28 21:48:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-09-28 21:48:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-09-28 21:48:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-09-28 21:48:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-09-28 21:48:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-09-28 21:48:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-09-28 21:48:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-09-28 21:48:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300288
2022-09-28 21:48:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-09-28 21:48:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2022-09-28 21:48:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-09-28 21:48:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-09-28 21:48:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-09-28 21:48:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-09-28 21:48:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 300297; transaction id 170
2022-09-28 21:48:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-09-28 21:48:11 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-09-28 21:48:11 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-09-28 21:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-09-28 21:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-09-28 21:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-09-28 21:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-09-28 21:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-09-28 21:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-09-28 21:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-09-28 21:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300306
2022-09-28 21:48:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-09-28 21:48:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2022-09-28 21:48:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-09-28 21:48:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-09-28 21:48:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-09-28 21:48:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-09-28 21:48:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 300315; transaction id 170
2022-09-28 21:48:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-09-28 21:48:58 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-09-28 21:48:58 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-09-28 22:14:47 0 [Note] mysqld.exe: Aria engine: starting recovery
recovered pages: 0% 25% 100% (0.0 seconds); tables to flush: 1 0
 (0.0 seconds); 
2022-09-28 22:14:48 0 [Note] mysqld.exe: Aria engine: recovery done
2022-09-28 22:14:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-09-28 22:14:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-09-28 22:14:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-09-28 22:14:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-09-28 22:14:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-09-28 22:14:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-09-28 22:14:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-09-28 22:14:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300324
2022-09-28 22:14:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-09-28 22:14:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2022-09-28 22:14:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-09-28 22:14:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-09-28 22:14:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-09-28 22:14:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-09-28 22:14:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 300333; transaction id 170
2022-09-28 22:14:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-09-28 22:14:48 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-09-28 22:14:48 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-09-28 22:15:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-09-28 22:15:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-09-28 22:15:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-09-28 22:15:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-09-28 22:15:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-09-28 22:15:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-09-28 22:15:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-09-28 22:15:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300342
2022-09-28 22:15:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-09-28 22:15:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2022-09-28 22:15:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-09-28 22:15:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-09-28 22:15:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-09-28 22:15:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-09-28 22:15:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 300351; transaction id 170
2022-09-28 22:15:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-09-28 22:15:46 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-09-28 22:15:46 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-09-28 22:16:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-09-28 22:16:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-09-28 22:16:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-09-28 22:16:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-09-28 22:16:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-09-28 22:16:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-09-28 22:16:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-09-28 22:16:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-09-28 22:16:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-09-28 22:16:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-09-28 22:16:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-09-28 22:16:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-09-28 22:16:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 300360; transaction id 170
2022-09-28 22:16:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-09-28 22:16:02 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-09-28 22:16:02 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-09-28 22:16:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-09-28 22:16:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-09-28 22:16:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-09-28 22:16:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-09-28 22:16:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-09-28 22:16:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-09-28 22:16:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-09-28 22:16:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-09-28 22:16:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-09-28 22:16:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-09-28 22:16:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-09-28 22:16:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-09-28 22:16:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 300369; transaction id 170
2022-09-28 22:16:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-09-28 22:16:30 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-09-28 22:16:30 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-09-28 22:16:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-09-28 22:16:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-09-28 22:16:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-09-28 22:16:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-09-28 22:16:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-09-28 22:16:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-09-28 22:16:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-09-28 22:16:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-09-28 22:16:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-09-28 22:16:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-09-28 22:16:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-09-28 22:16:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-09-28 22:16:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 300378; transaction id 170
2022-09-28 22:16:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-09-28 22:16:50 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-09-28 22:16:50 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-09-28 22:20:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-09-28 22:20:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-09-28 22:20:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-09-28 22:20:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-09-28 22:20:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-09-28 22:20:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-09-28 22:20:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-09-28 22:20:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-09-28 22:20:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-09-28 22:20:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-09-28 22:20:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-09-28 22:20:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-09-28 22:20:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 300387; transaction id 170
2022-09-28 22:20:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-09-28 22:20:17 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-09-28 22:20:17 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-09-28 22:31:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-09-28 22:31:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-09-28 22:31:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-09-28 22:31:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-09-28 22:31:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-09-28 22:31:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-09-28 22:31:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-09-28 22:31:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-09-28 22:31:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-09-28 22:31:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-09-28 22:31:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-09-28 22:31:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-09-28 22:31:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 300396; transaction id 170
2022-09-28 22:31:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-09-28 22:31:23 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-09-28 22:31:23 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: I didn't find any errors on the logs.

Did you check if some other application is using the default port?

Comment: Please post the last 100 lines of your error log for consistency analysis.

Comment: WOW that a very old version of mariaDB

Comment: @RiggsFolly  Wondering where you found mariaDB version in this question.

Comment: @WilsonHauck All over the log, `InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; `

Comment: @RiggsFolly You are so right.  Dropped the MariaDB, thanks.  It is not real old, Feb 12, 2022.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Well its an older version, the current long term support version being 10.6

Answer (score 0):

Update: uninstalled the app (XAMPP) then re installed, it now works mysql included. But i know as soon as i start installing things (moodle and such) it will stop again. Is something blocking 3306?
Going to keep testing it to see. The more i work with Windows 11, tbh, the less i like it.

Comment: Please update original question and delete this

Comment: The ANSWER box is for ANSWERS, not comments and not supposition